# Is there a rigourous proof about this :$(C)'=0$ , where C is any constant?

Tags: derivatives

Is there someone who can give me a rigourous proof about the derivative of any

constant $C$ is zero :$(C)'=0$

Note :I know only this for any real number  $x>0$:$(C=Cx^0)'=C'=0Cx^{0-0}=0.1=0$ ,are there others ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the derivative? (As a limit)?

Comment: yes i know , but is IT a rigourous proof ?

Comment: Why wouldn't using the definition be rigourous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=C$

$$f'(x_0) = \lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}= \lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{C - C}{x-x_0} = 0$$

Comment: Neatly, completely, and sweetly done!

Comment: is it a rigourous proof ? , you are just used the definition as the same what i cited in the question

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Yes this is as rigorous as you could hope for.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik This is the definition of a derivative. If you wanted everything "rigorous", you could prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} 0 = 0$ - but this is trivial (you can choose $\delta$ however you want in an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof)

Answer (score -4):

here two ways:
1) Use definition of derivative
2) Use mean value theorem to show if f'(c) = 0 then f(x1) = f(x2)

Comment: what is this  ? is it a rigourous proof ?

Comment: what do you mean by rigorous proof? I give you two different proof

Comment: Can someone tell me please, Why down voting?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would guess that it's because the first point isn't very much illustrated (and the second point proves "if $f'(x)=0$ then $f$ is constant, where what seems to be the question is the converse of that - though, all told, this is not a very clear question)

Comment: @Meelo what i say is completely same with upper post, where it was up voted 2 times. I don't know what is wrong. Can down-voters elaborate on that?

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but my guess is that they don't consider this an answer... the OP asked for a proof, and you didn't provide a proof.  Your answer seems more like a comment to me.

Comment: 1) There's more explanation in the answer that uses the limit definition of derivative than simply exhorting the Reader to "use definition of derivative".  2) This seems to be backwards in a two-fold way.  First we are asked to show the derivative of a constant is zero, but you start by assuming a zero derivative.  Also the Mean Value Thm. goes the other direction; if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then (according to MVT) there exists a point $x_3$ strictly between $x_1$ and $x_2$ where the derivative is zero.  This is much weaker than concluding the derivative is everywhere zero.

Comment: @hardmath  2) has missing part you are right. What i mean was if f'(x) is zero for all x, then it is constant function. But is this a considirable reason for down vote 4 times? I think not.

Comment: Your argument in (2) uses the MVT to show $f'(x) = 0$ everywhere implies $f(x)$ is constant, but this is the converse of what the Question asks.  I appreciate the clarification, but this is still going the wrong direction.  I'm sure you could carry out the details for (1), and doing so would (like the Accepted Answer) remove any doubts about whether using the limit definition of derivative gives a rigorous proof that the derivative of a constant is zero.